# Resize the image to div

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I have this code:

```css
.post-container {
  overflow: auto
}

.post-thumb {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-thumb img {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">
  <div class="post-thumb"><img src="../images/logo.png" /></div>
</div>
```

I want to show an Image who shouldn't get stretched. But right now the side creates a scrolling box to scroll the image in the width because the image is very long.

Comment: just set `.post-thumb img {max-width: 100%; width: 100%;}` instead of min-width

Comment: I believe your statement is contradicting itself. You don't want for the image to stretch but at the same time it shouldn't be it's original size when very long? Did you mean it should not increase over 100% width of it's parent while keeping proportions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try :

```
.post-thumb img {
  width:100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  display: block;
}
```

Tell me if this helps you or changes something.

Answer (score 0):

You can **scale** your image using a CSS style:

```
.post-thumb img{
  transform: scale(2,6); // example scale ( width, heigth )
}
```

Note: first look how [browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=scale) support this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest regular responsive setup as in

```
.post-thumb img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```